# How to switch between workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with switching between workbooks. Could you take a look at code and say what is wrong with attitude to problem which i am trying? Or propose some other way to do this.

```
Sub copy_spreadsheets()

Dim wb As Workbook, wb_main As Workbook, path As String, sheet_name As String, x As Integer, i As Integer, source_sheet As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet

path = "C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder\"
Set wb_main = ThisWorkbook
For x = 2 To 10
i = 2
sheet_name = ("sheet" & i & ".xlsx")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path & sheet_name)
Set sourceSheet = Worksheets("sheet1")
sourceSheet.Activate
sourceSheet.Cells.Select
Selection.Copy
Workbooks("C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder\sheet1.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Set ws = Sheets.Add

i = i + 1
Next x


End Sub
```

Comment: What is wrong with your code? What happens or doesn't happen? Are there errors?

Comment: You are also copying (the entire sheet(s)!) but never paste.

Comment: You should avoid using `Activate` to switch between workbooks. Instead, refer to sheets on that workbook explicitly: `Set sourceSheet = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")`

Answer (score -1):

There is a Workbook.Activate method as well as Worksheet.  Try activating the workbook before activating sheets within that workbook.

Comment: I've downvoted because you haven't even told OP where to activate a workbook, let alone why they need to do that. Note that OP did already try to activate a workbook towards the end of their code but used the wrong syntax in their `Workbooks()` call -- something you haven't even touched upon

Comment: OP is calling Activate on the sheet object, not the workbook.

Comment: With your advice above OP might change their code to `Workbooks("C:\Users\me\Desktop\folder\sheet1.xls").Activate`. Also broken. You don't need to point anything out to me, I am more than capable of seeing what's wrong with OPs code, I'm just telling you that this is not sufficient for OP. If you're here to help, you'll post more than two sentences as answers.

Comment: Why don't you post an answer then?  Bizarre.

Comment: @CallumDA: http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/488/486/8c0.png